# Using words instead of symbols to name variables

Tags: soft-question, notation

In programming, "single character" variable names are generally considered bad practice, since they make it more difficult to understand subsequent uses of the variable (one must refer back to the definition of each symbol in an expression, which is tedious and makes the expression more confusing). Instead, variable names should in some sense "summarize" their definition; i.e., for a remainder in a division algorithm, `remainder` or `rem` would be preferred over `r`, which is standard in number theory texts. That's not even the worst case, since at least `r` can be seen as an abbreviation of "remainder": often, the letters have nothing to do with their meanings!

Is there any reason, except for historical reasons, that we can't do the same in mathematics? Many theorems I've come across would be much easier to understand if some of their symbols were replaced by programmer-style identifiers. Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: The converse argument is that programming avoids single-letter variables because it is limited to latin characters. Now that some languages (notably Julia) support the full UTF-8 range as variable names, it is becoming a lot more common to see single-character variables used as identifiers or even operators in code.

Comment: Java also allows non-Latin characters in names; you can even use Chinese characters.  I have never seen it done in serious code even if it was written by a Chinese speaker.

Comment: Exacltly: historical reasons. In 16th Century the algebraic formulas were "described" with words; see John Fauvel & Jeremy Gray (editors), [The History of Mathematics: A Reader](https://books.google.it/books?id=kFwPAQAAMAAJ), MacMillan (1987), page 255, for Cardano and Tartaglia: "When the cube and the things together are equal to some discrete number..." i.e. $x^3+cx=d$. The modern symbolic way is much more practical.